# Automator Action Plugin in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, automator

I want to create an 'Action' in automator app. I am following [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2322/_index.html) apple documentation for it.
The documentation mentions using an 'automator action' system-plugin project to create the action. But I don't this option in my Xcode. Was this removed by apple? and is there an alternative to creating an automator action available now?

I m using Xcode version 14.2.

[image]

Comment: Xcode 14 no longer includes AppleScriptObjC application and Automator project templates, but they can be copied from Xcode 13 and added to your custom templates.